# ttk.Entry not setting default based on textvariable

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I have created following window with tkinter and ttk, however I simply can't force the ttk.Entry fields to follow textvariable for its default value, they just keep appearing as blank. Strangely sometimes when I actually cause an exception to occur elsewhere in the window they suddenly work.

```
class PopUpEdit:
    def __init__(self, idx):
        self.idx = idx
        self.data = get_single(self.idx)

        self.have = tk.StringVar(root)
        self.site = tk.StringVar(root)
        self.title = tk.StringVar(root)
        self.tags = tk.StringVar(root)

        self._setup_vars()
        self._setup_window()

    def _setup_window(self):
        window = tk.Toplevel(root)
        window.geometry('400x600')
        pprint.pprint(self.data)
        ttk.Label(window, text='Site').grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)
        ttk.Entry(window, textvariable=self.site, width=40).grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='e', pady=10, padx=10)
        ttk.Label(window, text='Title').grid(row=3, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)
        ttk.Entry(window, textvariable=self.title, width=40).grid(row=3, column=2, sticky='e', pady=10, padx=10)
        ttk.Label(window, text=self.data['id']).grid(row=4, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)

    def _setup_vars(self):
        self.title.set(self.data['title'])
        self.site.set(self.data['site'])
        self.tags.set(self.data['tags'])
```

Comment: You don't show what `get_single(self.idx)` does. Have you verified that it's returning what you assume it's returning?

Comment: Yeah, it works fine (returns a dict with keys title, site tags and idx), and when I do self.title.get() it also returns correct value